# How to Enable/Disable button in wpf

Tags: wpf

I Have 2 button , Start And capture. I want disable capture button on form load and enable start. and on after click on start disable start button and enable capture. 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Edit

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,151,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/images.jpg" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,151,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" IsEnabled="False" >
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/images.jpg" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @user3721563 did it solve your problem?

Comment: @vlad - I did not use MVVM

Comment: You need to show your code about what you tried so far. Otherwise people here have to guess your implementation and provide answers.

Comment: both button having same image. but I dont want disable look. directly disappear from UI

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="BStart" Content="Start" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="BStart_Click" />
        <Button Name="BCapture" Content="Capture" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="False" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]
you can disable Capture by xaml and then enable it by writing code in c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BStart.IsEnabled = false;
            BCapture.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

for enable and disable use IsEnabled Property. and for clicking on the button use Click event.

Comment: Thanks For Such great explanation. But I have same image on both button. So the user cannot understand about which button were click. Both button are on same place

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it too, but could someone please explain why the top answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555996/dynamically-creating-list-of-buttons-in-wpf-application emphatically emphasizes "you shouldn't be programmatically altering the UI until you know when you should do that" (ie. when is it okay to programmatically is `BStart.IsEnabled`?)

Answer (score 2):

Set IsEnabled="False" to disable the button

```
<Button Name="btn" IsEnabled="False" Content="press"/>
```

Set IsEnabled="True" to enable the button

```
<Button Name="btn" IsEnabled="True" Content="press"/>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: could you please explain with some XAML ?

Answer (score 1):

You should store current state in some variable (e.g. `_capturing`). When variable changing, you refresh `IsEnabled` property.

Xaml code:

```
<Button Content="Start" Name="StartButton" Grid.Row="0" Click="StartButton_Click" />
<Button Content="Capture" Name="CaptureButton" Grid.Row="1" Click="CaptureButton_Click"/>
```

C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool _capturing;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Some code

        _capturing = false;
        UpdateButtons();
    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Some code

        _capturing = true;
        UpdateButtons();
    }

    private void CaptureButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Some code

        UpdateButtons();
    }

    private void UpdateButtons()
    {
        StartButton.IsEnabled = !_capturing;
        CaptureButton.IsEnabled = _capturing;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You should add click handler and your xaml code will work:

```
<Button Click="StartButton_Click" Content="Button" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,151,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/images.jpg" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
<Button Click="CaptureButton_Click" Content="Button" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,151,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" IsEnabled="False" >
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/images.jpg" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: Yes. You can replace buttons to any place in xaml file.

Comment: Will u please explain. I want to override buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I got my answer. Just make simeple solution

```
btnhide.visibility= system.visibility. hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to disable a button In C# WPF.

1. In `.xaml` File
    Using `IsEnabled="False"`. If you set False to `IsEnabled` attribute, then your button will be disabled by default.
2. In `.cs` File
    `ButtonName.IsEnabled = false;` If you set `IsEnabled` property as false for the button, it will disable the button