# How to deal with asynchronous button clicks in TicTacToe game with a bot?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, tic-tac-toe

I'm currently working on a simple UI for TicTacToe using C# and WPF in order to learn them. I'm trying to replicate all of the functionalities of the small TicTacToe game you can play when you type Tic Tac Toe on google. All the game logic and the Bot is working perfectly but I'm having problems merging the logic with the UI. This is my code (I'm ommiting the game logic code as I think it's not relevant here and the code has enough abstraction):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Game _game;

        private Dictionary<string, Button> _buttons;

        private bool _cellPressOnQueue;

        private bool _restartPressOnQueue;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _game = new Game(false, 1);
            _buttons = board.Children.OfType<Button>().ToDictionary<Button, string, Button>(
                v => v.Name.ToString().Substring(1, 2), v => v);
            _cellPressOnQueue = false;
            _restartPressOnQueue = false;
        }

        private async void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_cellPressOnQueue || _restartPressOnQueue ) return;

            _cellPressOnQueue = true;

            Button button = (Button)sender;
            string pos = button.Name.ToString().Substring(1, 2);

            if (_game.CheckGameState() == 'C')
            {
                _game.UpdateBoard(pos);
                _game.UpdatePlayer();
                PrintSymbol(pos);

                if (_game.BotIsPlaying)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1500);

                    string posBot = _game.BotTurn();
                    if (posBot != null) PrintSymbol(posBot);
                }
            }
            _cellPressOnQueue = false;
        }

        private async void RestartClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //UnsubscribingButtons();
            _restartPressOnQueue = true;
            ReenableButtons();
            _game.SetupBoard();
            _game.Current = 0;
            //SubscribingButtons();
            _restartPressOnQueue = false;
        }

        private void ReenableButtons()
        {
            board.Children.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(Button =>
            {
                Button.IsEnabled = true;
                Button.Content = " ";
            });
        }

        private void PrintSymbol(string pos)
        {
            Button button = _buttons[pos];
            button.IsEnabled = false;
            button.Content = _game.Players[_game.Current].Symbol;
        }


        private void UnsubscribingButtons()
        {
            board.Children.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(Button =>
            {
                Button.Click -= ButtonClick;
                
            });
        }

        private void SubscribingButtons()
        {
            board.Children.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(Button =>
            {
                Button.Click += ButtonClick;

            });
        }

    }
```

In the current way I have my code, by pressing one of the cells in the board (to make my move), the Bot then needs to choose its move but the problem is that while this is happening I can still click on other cells and the game bugs out. My first way to stop this was by using the boolean _cellPressOnQueue which would tell if a button click is still being processed. This way doesn't seem good and I was wondering what is optimal way to treat this (maybe remove the Bot section from ButtonClick and use Events and EventHandling?). The last problem is the restart button which clears the board and restarts the match. Currently what happens is that if I click on a cell and then on the restart button it clears the board but since the bot is still choosing this move (take note that I add a 1.5 seconds delay on this since I don't want his play to appear imediately on the board). Once again I tried using a boolean but didn't like its results. Unsubscribing and subscribing from the ButtonClick event also didn't work as it was slow.
So my question is: how would these things be treated/done on a real app? What kind of elements from .NET would I have to use?

Comment: Sounds like some buttons should only be clicked at certain times. You need to figure out what those times are and [enable/disable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338223/how-to-enable-disable-button-in-wpf/28338400) as needed.

Comment: Disabling buttons that the user shouldn't click is preferable. See duplicate. Alternatively, you can change the code to just ignore button input when there shouldn't be any.

Comment: Sorry but disabling and enabling buttons seems lazy to solve the problem